# Recommend a design pattern for a workflow application

Tags: c#, design-patterns, user-interface, workflow, workflow-foundation

I am developing an application where the users can execute tasks / workflows. Each task is made up of a queue of actions to be executed. I want to be able to be able to have user input after the workflow is started.

**Example:**

- Task starts

  - Action1 starts
  - Action1 ends
  - Action2 starts
  - Action2 ends
  - Action3 needs user input (UI opens window to get user input)
  - Action3 gets user input
  - Action3 starts
  - Action3 ends
- Task ends

I am developing this i C# and I am aware of Workflow Foundation and tasks in C#. They may have what I need, but I am also interested in hearing about a design pattern for doing this from scratch.

Comment: The "re-invent the wheel" pattern?!? You already know the right way to do this, why are you trying to do it from scratch? Not Invented Here fear?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have described is the [Sequence Workflow Pattern](http://www.workflowpatterns.com/patterns/control/basic/wcp1.php).

There are more Workflow Patterns at the [Workflow Patterns initiative](http://www.workflowpatterns.com/patterns/) and in [MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee294452.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I think the following articles can help you with the async task part:

[The Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://www.nikosbaxevanis.com/bonus-bits/2010/10/async-ctp-part-1.html)

[TPL and Traditional .NET Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423.aspx)